# When should I use partial pivoting in Gaussian elimination?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, systems-of-equations, gaussian-elimination

Is there any criterion to decide whether to use naive Gaussian elimination or Gaussian elimination with partial pivoting?

Why should I use partial pivoting if naive Gaussian elimination gives me the correct result?

By the way, I don't program it. I use paper and pencil. Thank you.

Comment: not only that, but it's also used to avoid division by zero.

Comment: Well, if you're using pencil and paper, you are using arbitrary-precision rational arithmetic (I hope), which means you don't have to worry about round-off error. You do have to worry about division by zero, though.

Answer (score 0):

If you perform the computation with paper and pencil, partial pivoting has no cost at all. Unless you are working with exact arithmetic, go for it !

Comment: @RodrigodeAzevedo: not necessarily, you may opt for fixed point or other (or receive data in this format).